# Flex4.6 Add element to top of List

Tags: list, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, arraylist

I've got a spark list that gets dynamically filled.
So far the new items appear at the bottom of the list. What I'd like to do is to add them at the top.

The items in the list have a unique ID so some kind of sorting mechanism would probably do the trick as the new items have a greater ID than the old ones.

What I'd like to avoid is some complex method behind this as I'm working on a mobile platform and the list can get quite big so I need this to be as efficient as possible.

The list's data provider is an ArrayList that gets updated using binding.

How can that be done?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes the solution can be that simple. Cheers mate! Is there a way to mark this as the answer?

Comment: Eh, well. I'm not going to post the same answer twice since umar already did. Let's just say I was too lazy to write something more than two words :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can Add the items at the starting index of the datagrid. Flex datagrid automatically renew all the indexes and add 1 to all existing element indexes. So

`YourDataGridId.dataprovider.addItemAt(item,0)` will do.

Comment: If you copy, make sure you don't copy the mistakes. That should be `addItemAt(someItem, 0)` instead of `addItemAt(0)`.

Comment: sorry, didn't pay attention to that